# Accessing resources with a LWJGL applet

Tags: java, applet, classloader, lwjgl

I have a game made in LWJGL that I am trying to port to an applet. After my first attempt, I realized that I could not use `new FileReader(path)` for the applet and found that I should use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path)` I then put the resource folder into the main src location in eclipse. When I ran it using eclipse's applet viewer, it seemed to work fine. Then I exported the jar including the resources. I set up the html like the basicapplet that is included with the LWJGL applet files. However, when I run it, it crashes each time, because it can't load the resources. Now, `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(path)` seems to be returning null; I am sure that the res file is located in the root directory of my jar. Could it be that the loader is loading from some where else? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checked casesensitivity of file?

Comment: The files should be the same, and they worked in eclipse

Comment: *"they worked in eclipse"*  Eclipse might have been finding the loose resource, in which case the (upper/lower) case used for the name might not matter.  In a Jar, the paths are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If the resources are inside the games jar file I used this.
`this.getClass().getResource("/imgfolder/image.png")` to reach a resource within a jar.
If it's outside the jar I just use [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).